# How to serialize and deserialize HttpMessage or HttpContent in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I am using netty5. And, I am trying to read the http headers to get information from a http connection then just resend all the messages from that channel to another destination based on the header information. Is there  a way to serialize/deserialize HttpContent and HttpMessage into byte array? Or is there a better way to  do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the headers of request, here is a example snippet taking from netty's source code:  [HttpSnoopServerHandler.java](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java)

```
public class HttpSnoopServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
            HttpRequest request = this.request = (HttpRequest) msg;
            HttpHeaders headers = request.headers();
            if (!headers.isEmpty()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> h: headers) {
                    String key = h.getKey();
                    String value = h.getValue();
                    buf.append("HEADER: ").append(key).append(" = ").append(value).append("\r\n");
                }
                buf.append("\r\n");
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however it is just 1/2 of what I want. I need to route package based on http request headers so I need to parse the header first then somehow turn that http message/content into bytes to write it to another channel.